# Is Cat the vahana of Devi Shasthi according to any scripture?

Tags: identification-request

[image]

In Bengal, a cat is shown as the Vahana of Devi Shasthi, as shown in the enclosed image. But I did not find any Dhyana-Mantra of Devi Sasthi mentioning this.

Can anyone provide the scriptural reference?